# In Gossip GenServer processes dying before exit condition

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am creating multiple `GenServers` gossiping by sending message to each others. I have set an exit condition to make every process die once it has received 10 messages. Each `GenServer` is created at the beginning of the gossip in the `launch` function.

```rb
defmodule Gossip do
    use GenServer

    # starting gossip
    def start_link(watcher \\ nil), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, watcher)
    def init(watcher), do: {:ok, {[],0,watcher}}
    def launch(n, watcher \\ nil) do
        crew = (for _ <- 0..n, do: elem(Gossip.start_link(watcher),1))
        Enum.map(crew, &(add_crew(&1,crew--[&1])))
        crew
            |> hd()
            |> Gossip.send_msg()
    end 


    # client side
    def add_crew(pid, crew), do: GenServer.cast(pid, {:add_crew, crew})
    def rcv_msg(pid, msg \\ ""), do: GenServer.cast(pid, {:rcv_msg, msg})
    def send_msg(pid, msg \\ ""), do: GenServer.cast(pid, {:send_msg, msg})


    # server side  
    def handle_cast({:add_crew, crew}, {_, msg_counter, watcher}), do:
        {:noreply, {crew, msg_counter, watcher}}

    def handle_cast({:rcv_msg, _msg}, {crew, msg_counter, watcher}) do
        if msg_counter < 10 do
            send_msg(self())
        else
            GossipWatcher.increase(watcher)
            IO.inspect(self(), label: "exit of:") |> Process.exit(:normal)
        end
        {:noreply, {crew, msg_counter+1, watcher}}
    end

    def handle_cast({:send_msg,_},{[],_,_}), do: Process.exit(self(),"crew empty")
    def handle_cast({:send_msg, _msg}, {crew, msg_counter, watcher}=state) do
        rcpt = Enum.random(crew) ## recipient of the msg
        if Process.alive?(rcpt) do
            IO.inspect({self(),rcpt}, label: "send message from/to")
            rcv_msg(rcpt, "ChitChat")
            send_msg(self())
            {:noreply, state}
        else
        IO.inspect(rcpt, label: "recipient is dead:")
        {:noreply, {crew -- [rcpt], msg_counter, watcher}}
        end
    end
end


defmodule GossipWatcher do
    use GenServer

    def start_link(opt \\ []), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opt)
    def init(opt), do: {:ok, {0}}
    def increase(pid), do: GenServer.cast(pid, {:increase})  
    def handle_cast({:increase}, {counter}), do:
        IO.inspect({:noreply, {counter+1}}, label: "toll of dead")

end
```

I use the module `GossipWatcher` to monitor that number of `GenServer` who dies, after having received 10 messages. The issue is that **the `iex` prompt back whereas there are still some `GenServers` alive**. For example over 1000 `GenServer`, only ~964 `GenServers` die at the end of the gossip.

```rb
iex(15)> {:ok, watcher} = GossipWatcher.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.11163.0>}
iex(16)> Gossip.launch 100, watcher            
send message from/to: {#PID<0.11165.0>, #PID<0.11246.0>}
:ok     
send message from/to: {#PID<0.11165.0>, #PID<0.11167.0>}
send message from/to: {#PID<0.11246.0>, #PID<0.11182.0>}
send message from/to: {#PID<0.11165.0>, #PID<0.11217.0>}
...
toll of dead: {:noreply, {960}}
toll of dead: {:noreply, {961}}
toll of dead: {:noreply, {962}}
toll of dead: {:noreply, {963}}
toll of dead: {:noreply, {964}}
iex(17)>
```

Am I missing something here ? Is the process timing out ? Any help would be appreciated
TIA.

Comment: @NathanRipert Here you go http://paste.openstack.org/show/731176/ .Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: It does not exit, but I get my command prompt back. I want the process to keep on sending messages till the counter value is reached. I might be wrong to assume that the returning of command prompt is exiting.

Comment: Please feel free to do that . Awesome work @NathanRipert debugging this issue.

Comment: I find the edit good. I try to post questions as much generic as possible but I think the editing was necessary over here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of your code that can play some tricks is here:

```rb
def handle_cast({:send_periodic_message}, zero_counter_gossip_true) do

    ...

    if (Process.alive?(rcpt)) == true do

    ...

    else
        IO.inspect(rcpt, label: "recipient is dead:")
        {:noreply, {crew -- [rcpt], msg_counter, watcher}}
    end
end
```

In this part of the else, you allow the `GenServer` **to stop working**: since it does not send a message to a neighbor or himself, no "action" are launched and it simply stop doing something.
In the worst and unlikely case possible: if you start 2000 `GenServer` and launch the gossip from one `GenServer`, and that this first one only talks to a second one which also only talk to the first one.... then only one `GenServer` is going to die, and you get back the command prompt, with still 1999 `GenServer` alive but doing nothing (since they are receiving 0 messages).

Even if this case is far fetched, it shows that the execution of the gossip can end prematurely before every `GenServer` has received 10 messages. Hence the behavior you describe.

---

I did some test, [rewriting your code](http://paste.openstack.org/show/731212/), and using a second type of `GenServer` to monitor how many `GenServers` are killed, and how many survive. It turns out that out of 1000 `GenServers`, I get an average of 40 `GenServer` still alive after I got back the `iex` prompt.

Comment: It was great thinking on your part to think about all this. I actually was hitting the same issue, 960/1000 dead or maybe less sometime or maybe sometimes more.